# 'observeEvent' function into another 'observeEvent' function not working

Tags: r, shiny

Following is the toned down version of my original problem. Here I am
trying to run an 'observeEvent' function into another 'observeEvent'
function. The code should perform the following steps sequentially:

1. On click of 'Print' button, Print the input number
2. On click of 'Add' button, Add +5 with the printed number

The code is working for first time only. From second time it is
showing the added  number along with the printed without any click on
'Add' button.

Please help.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    sliderInput("n", min = 0, max = 100, value = 50, label = "Choose a number"),
    actionButton("Print","Print the number"),
    verbatimTextOutput("num1"),
    actionButton("Add","Add +5 to the printed number"),
    verbatimTextOutput("num2")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){
  all <- reactiveValues(
    n = 50,
    a = 55
  )

  observeEvent(input$Print,{
    all$n <- input$n
    output$num1 <- renderPrint(all$n)

    observeEvent(input$Add,{
      all$d <- input$n + 5
      output$num2 <- renderPrint(all$d)
    })

  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: `observeEvent` by definition will trigger anything inside it. Separate them and use `all$n` in the second `observeEvent` i.e. in `input$Add`

Comment: Yes. It is working.. Thanks again Suliman.

Comment: Can you please include the full code that works, as an answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you separate them, you can make the second `observeEvent` to get triggered from whatever happens inside the first one.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    sliderInput("n", min = 0, max = 100, value = 50, label = "Choose a number"),
    actionButton("Print","Print the number"),
    verbatimTextOutput("num1"),
    actionButton("Add","Add +5 to the printed number"),
    verbatimTextOutput("num2")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){
  all <- reactiveValues(
    n = 50,
    a = 55
  )

  observeEvent(input$Print, {
    all$n <- input$n
    output$num1 <- renderPrint(all$n)
  })

   observeEvent(all$n, {
     all$d <- input$n + 5
     output$num2 <- renderPrint(all$d)
   })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```